# How to configure url mapping in web.xml to restrict access?

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I have few pages in following structure.

```
--Project
  |---WebContect
      |----Admin/ *
      |----Author/ * 
      |----Readonly/ * 
      |----Index.jsp
```

I want to restrict the user from accessing Pages under `Admin`,`Author` and `Readonly`. I don't want anybody to access these pages. And if somebody tries to do so, should be redirected to `index.jsp`.

The easiest solution that come in my mind is using a `Filter`, but I am trying to find if its possible to do using `web.xml`.

Comment: Or in other words I want allow access of 'index.jsp' only irrespective of role or authorization.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want that *nobody* is able to access those pages directly, just put them in `/WEB-INF` folder.

```
Project
 `-- WebContect
      |-- WEB-INF
      |    |-- Admin
      |    |-- Author
      |    `-- Readonly
      `-- Index.jsp
```

This way the pages are not publicly accessible, but only by a servlet which performs a forward. When the enduser attempts to access it directly, all he will get is a HTTP 404 error.

An alternative is configuring a role-less `<security-constraint>`.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to certain folders</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted folders</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Admin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Author/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Readonly/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

When the enduser attempts to access them, all he will get is a HTTP 403 error.

Either way, it isn't possible to redirect the enduser to `index.jsp` this way. Only a `Filter` can do that. You *could* configure the `index.jsp` as error page location for 404 or 403

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

But this would cover *all* 404's (or 403's), not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Agree with you, handling 404 with index.jsp would be a bad Idea.I would even happy, if am able to achieve 1st part only.

Comment: Then I think keeping to be a 404 is just fine. Why would the enduser only get redirected to the index page for only a specific set of URLs which the enduser shouldn't even be aware of? Do you have all existing links somewhere around in the web which points to those restricted URLs? Well, then you really can't go around a filter for that. Make sure that the filter performs a 301 redirect, not a 302 redirect, this way searchbots will remove the old URL from the index.

Comment: Agree, enduser should be aware of any restricted urls that he is trying to access. Secondly, none of the link has gone public yet, so your point makes scene

Answer (score 0):

you have try this ?    (sample for url mapping)

```
<security-constraint>   
                <web-resource-collection>   
                        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>   
                        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   
                </web-resource-collection>   

                <auth-constraint>   
<--! These are the groups in AD -->   
                        <role-name>Engineering</role-name>   
                        <role-name>Migration Expert</role-name>   
                        <role-name>Developers</role-name>   

                </auth-constraint>   
        </security-constraint>   

  <security-constraint>   
   <web-resource-collection>   
      <url-pattern>/update/*</url-pattern>   
   </web-resource-collection>   
  </security-constraint>   

        <login-config>   
                <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>   
                <realm-name>Services Portal</realm-name>   
        </login-config>
```

Comment: Sorry i hae found a sample here with sample and control authentification in url mapping... i try help. http://www.coderanch.com/t/584071/Tomcat/Exclude-url-authorized-access-web

Comment: Why are you copypasting snippets you found in Google while you're not understanding at all what you're actually answering? Just answer questions only which you can answer from top of head and can explain its workings in detail.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to grand access to pages/folders by role permission you have to have a  **security-constraint** in your web-xml file

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>DESC_OF_FOLDER</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>REGISTERED_USER_ROLE</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

The role can be acquired by this code if you are using standard Jaas authentication

```
        if ((request.getUserPrincipal().getName()) != null) {
            String userName = request.getUserPrincipal().getName().trim();
            .....

            if (request.isUserInRole("REGISTERED_USER_ROLE")) {
                .....
            } 
         }
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

And for the redirection to the login page you should have also something like this in the web.xml

```
<form-login-config>
  <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
  <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```